# How to exclude a class from MNIST in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, mnist

I am new to TensorFlow and I am following the tutorial for beginners with MNIST data set and I want to train the model just with the 0-8 (excluding the class 9), so where in the code was 10, I replaced it to 9, but at the training part of code, how to ask the `next_batch()` to exclude the class 9 ? And if I want to exclude more than one class?

```python
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import argparse
import sys

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

import tensorflow as tf

FLAGS = None

def main(_):
  # Import data
  mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(FLAGS.data_dir, one_hot=True)

  # Create the model
  x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
  W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 9]))  # was 10 instead of 9 
  b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([9]))      # was 10 instead of 9
  y = tf.matmul(x, W) + b

  # Define loss and optimizer
  y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 9]) # was 10 instead of 9

  cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
      tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))
  train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

  sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
  tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
  # Train
  for _ in range(1000):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)    # How to exclude the class 9 ?
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

  # Test trained model
  correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
  accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
  print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images,
                                      y_: mnist.test.labels}))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument('--data_dir', type=str, default='/tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data',
                      help='Directory for storing input data')
  FLAGS, unparsed = parser.parse_known_args()
  tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pull the training data out of the mnist data object, dropping the class you want, and then proceed.  First get the dataset without class `9` in it:

```
Xdata_no9 = np.array([x for (x,y) in zip(mnist.train.images,mnist.train.labels) if y[9]==0])
ydata_no9 = np.array([y[0:9] for y in mnist.train.labels if y[9]==0])
```

Note that the `y[0:9]` reduces the size to `9` from `10`. That will do it, but now you need to build your own code to pull a minibatch.  Here's a simple way to do so:

```
n = Xdata_no9.shape[0]
batch_size = 100
batch = np.floor(np.random.rand(batch_size)*n).astype(int)
batch_xs = Xdata_no10[batch,:]
batch_ys = ydata_no10[batch,:]
```

Note that you can compress this code a bit, but I have written it to be instructive.

**Note of Caution**: doing this (dropping the class from your training set) is better practice: if you don't want to train on part of your data, you should remove it from your dataset early on, rather than require every call to that data to remember what part of the data should be ignored.  In this example it doesn't much matter as you only use it in training, but this of course would then break if you tried to evaluate performance on the whole training set (unless you remembered to ignore that class again).

Answer (score 1):

This line should do it right after you get `batch_xs` and `batch_ys`:

```
batch_xs, batch_ys = zip(*[(x_, y_[:-1]) for x_, y_ in zip(batch_xs, batch_ys) if np.argmax(y_) not in [9]])
```

Comment: But the output will continue being 10 values instead of 9 that is desired.

Comment: Ah, good catch. Need to squeeze `y_` there. Should be `y_[:-1]` (-2 for two classes, etc)

Comment: OK, but if I want to exclude the class `7` the `y_[:-1]` will remove the `9` instead.

Comment: If you intend to go this way, you should ordinal encoding, not one-hot. This will simplify everything